# Boolean comparison in python

Tags: python, syntax, boolean-logic

Python seems to evaluate oddly with (what I thought) would be relatively straightforward syntax. Can anyone shed light on what's happening behind the scenes here? What does python think is happening in the first case?

```
>>> x = 'foo'
>>> 'f' in x == True
False
>>> ('f' in x) == True
True
>>> 'f' in (x == True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

Comment: first line is like `f in x` and `x == True` (chaining comparisons). there's a dupe somewhere. you need `'f' in x` anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here is [**chained comparisons**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

```
'f' in x == True
```

Both `in` and `==` are both comparisons. Now Python interprets *chained* comparison interpreters with an *implicit* `and`. So you have basically written:

```
'f' in x and x == True
```

and the second check fails.

The same occurs if you for instance write:

```
a < b in c
```

it is short for:

```
a < b and b in c
```

(except that expressions are only evaluated once).

If we take a look at the documentation, we see that there are 11 comparators:

> ```
> comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "<>" | "!="
>                    | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
> ```

and furthermore it states:

> Comparisons can be **chained arbitrarily**, e.g., `x < y <= z` is
>   equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that **`y` is evaluated only
>   once** (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is
>   found to be `false`).
>
> Formally, if `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `y`, `z` are expressions and `op1`,
>   `op2`, ..., `opN` are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y
>   opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except
>   that each expression is evaluated at most once.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the answer I was looking for, with a link to the documentation. I'll accept this answer as soon as it lets me :)